# What method is used in PitchTap in AudioKit?

Tags: audiokit, pitch-tracking

Does someone know what pitch tracker is implemented in AudioKit? I couldn't find any clues in the source code. We are using it in scientific research and a reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It uses Soundpipe.

https://llllllll.co/t/lower-level-audio-programming/1259/31?page=2

"Soundpipe has adopted a pitch tracking algorithm originally written by Miller Puckette, adapted from the ptrack opcode in Csound. It is a very portable opcode written in c99-compliant C code. It is also the main pitch tracker used by AudioKit."